# NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ls/DocumentLS - issue occurring only on deployment after having fixed it on compile time

Tags: java, maven, java-11, xerces

### Background

I have a project where I parse some XML documents and I happened to need the `xerces` dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

While writing the unit tests with `junit4`, I had an issue every time I was running a unit test, which was the following and occurring every time I was compiling with `mvn clean install`:

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.346 s <<< FAILURE! - in ConversionTest
[ERROR] ConversionTest.initializationError  Time elapsed: 0.054 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ls/DocumentLS
        at ConversionTest.fromDirectory(ConversionTest.java:92)
        at ConversionTest.data(ConversionTest.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ls.DocumentLS
        at ConversionTest.fromDirectory(ConversionTest.java:92)
        at ConversionTest.data(ConversionTest.java:65)
```

### Compile-time solution

Searching the web, I have realized that I needed to add a new dependency to my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

After doing this, the tests compiled fine and I could produce my `.jar` which was packaged with the following build plug-in:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.company.tools.Application</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

... and compiled with the following settings:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>cp1252</encoding>
                <release>11</release>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <meminitial>128m</meminitial>
                <maxmem>512m</maxmem>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-Xpkginfo:always</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

This produced a `.jar` which contains all the required dependencies, here including the famous `org/w3c/dom/ls/DocumentLS`:

[image]

### Deployment

Now I move this `.jar` into my server and try to run it with the following command:

```
java -jar myJar.jar <inputs>
```

When I do that, I get the following exception, again!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ls/DocumentLS
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:801)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:699)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:622)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:580)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.newDocumentBuilder(Unknown Source)
        at com.company.tools.impl.FileProviderImpl.getXmlFile(FileProviderImpl.java:68)
        at com.company.tools.impl.FileProviderImpl.<init>(FileProviderImpl.java:38)
        at com.company.tools.impl.FileProviderImpl$Builder.build(FileProviderImpl.java:91)
        at com.company.tools.Application.main(Application.java:50)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ls.DocumentLS
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 15 more
```

### My question and some details about the machines

I am a bit lost here. I've added the dependency to my `pom.xml`, the class is well packaged inside the `.jar`, but still I have the same issue. 
What am I doing wrong?

If it can help:

*My machine*:

```
Java version: 11.0.2-BellSoft, vendor: BellSoft, runtime: C:\jdk-11.0.2
Default locale: fr_FR, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

*My server*:

```
openjdk version "11" 2018-09-25
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11+28)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11+28, mixed mode)
OS: Linux myServerAddress 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 29 17:29:29 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try with this version `2.12.0` ?

Comment: @Sambit same issue, unfortunately

Comment: Check this link. https://github.com/capstone-coal/coal-sds/issues/32.

Comment: @Sambit if I check the fix made, I understand that he was having some of his dependencies referencing a different version of the xercesImpl which was conflicting with the wanted one. But it’s not my case, I basically have no dependencies in Pom except for xerces and junit with scope test...

Comment: @Sambit you were finally right, the answer was in the issue on Github you suggested, I just didn't see it coming as I couldn't imagine the interface was pulling a transitive dependency on the implementation (+ the dependency tree in maven wasn't seeing it). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I ended up finding the solution thanks to @Sambit second comment about [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/capstone-coal/coal-sds/issues/32). Posting the answer here hoping it can save someone else days of headache!

Basically, I had this in my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In both cases (unit test and main code), the exception was raised by this code:

```
try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file)) {
    documents.put(file.getName(), DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(is));
}
```

... specifically, by the call to `newDocumentBuilder()` which was looking for an implementation of type `DocumentImpl`.

### Issue explanation

The first dependency `xerces` is pulling a transitive dependency on a deprecated version of `xercesImpl`. 
Hence, when I was running my tests, the code was compiling (because the dependency was there) but when the `newDocumentBuilder()` was looking for the `DocumentImpl`, the implementation was returned by the bad dependency which was looking for `org/w3c/dom/ls/DocumentLS` without success, so raising the `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Once I added the explicit dependency to `xercesImpl` in my pom, the `junit` runner understood that instead of searching the `DocumentImpl` in the deprecated version of `xercesImpl`, it should have been looked for in the explicit dependency so the issue was solved.

However, the JVM running the program on the server wasn't taking the same assumption: the `newDocumentBuilder()` was still looking for `DocumentImpl` inside the transitive dependency, so the issue was still there.

### Resolution

Get rid of the transitive dependency:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: You can also just revert the order of these two dependencies :
  <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

Maven takes the first call so you don't need to exclude xercesImpl in xerces if you call it before.

Comment: Great.. solved similar issue to my spring boot project as well